# Replace value of specific keys in flat arrays and also in nested arrays by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I use the following script to change some characters of the values in a flat array of objects. But sometimes my array could also be nested. In this case, my script doesn't work. How could I, let's say, dynamically replace the values for all keys 'id'? schemaRaw is a parsed JSON.

```
function justifyKeys(schemaRaw) {
  for (const obj of schemaRaw) {
    obj.id = obj.id.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, '_');
  }
  return schemaRaw;
}
```

Example flat array:

```
[{
"id": "_version_",
"alias": "_version_",
"dataType": "string",
"description": ""
}, {
"id": "author",
"alias": "author",
"dataType": "string",
"description": ""
}]
```

Example for nested array:

```
{
"xyz_306976964": [{
    "id": "classification_status_306976964",
    "alias": "classification_status_306976964",
    "dataType": "string",
    "description": ""
}],
"basicsArray": [{
    "id": "_version_",
    "alias": "_version_",
    "dataType": "string",
    "description": ""
}]
}
```

Comment: Do you know how deeply nested it can possibly be or is there no limit? Do you have an example of the data structure?

Comment: please provide some exmaple snippet

Comment: Also does it need to _come out_ with the same structure or are you looking for a flattened array when you're done?

Comment: I've added examples. It goes max. to level (1)

Comment: @mm1975 do you want to end up with a flattened array?

Comment: @maxshuty, no I would like to keep the structure, only replace the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below method help you.

```
Object.prop = function (obj, prop, val) {
            var props = prop.split('.')
              , final = props.pop(), p
            while (p = props.shift()) {
                if (typeof obj[p] === 'undefined')
                    return undefined;
                obj = obj[p]
            }
            return val ? (obj[final] = val) : obj[final]
        }
function justifyKeys(schemaRaw) {
  schemaRaw=RecursiveChange(schemaRaw)
  return schemaRaw;
}

function RecursiveChange(objData){
   Object.prop(objData, "id", objData.id.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, '_'));
   if(objData.length>0){
       for (const obj of objData) {
           Object.prop(obj, "id", obj.id.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, '_'));
           if(obj.length>0){
              RecursiveChange(obj);
           }
       }
   }
    return objData
}
```

Comment: Thx! I get an error in the first line of the function RecursiveChange. "obj is not defined"

Comment: Oh sry i forgot to change the name of variable. let me edit & please let me know if it not work i want to learn

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more flexible, iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { xyz_306976964: [{ id: '@@@@classification_status_306976964', alias: 'classification_status_306976964', dataType: 'string', description: '' }], basicsArray: [{ id: '$$$$_version_', alias: '_version_', dataType: 'string', description: '' }] };

objectScan(['**.id'], {
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value }) => {
    parent[property] = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, '_');
  }
})(data);

console.log(data);
// => { xyz_306976964: [ { id: '_classification_status_306976964', alias: 'classification_status_306976964', dataType: 'string', description: '' } ], basicsArray: [ { id: '__version_', alias: '_version_', dataType: 'string', description: '' } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)